# If else not working (comparison operator in Django)

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am using Django 1.11 and I am trying to use the Django templating to do an `if .. else ..` statement in a html file.

Regular `if .. else ..` statements work in the Django templating, the only issue I am running into is using the comparison operators (`<=, <, >, >=`).

I have re-read the docs for Django 1.11 and it definitely seems like it is supported in this version.

Code (view / database):

`a = 25.2  # passed from view to database`

HTML template

```
{% if data.a < 30 %}
    <p>correct</p>
{% else %}
    <p>incorrect</p>
{% endif %}
```

By itself `data.a` works fine, if I just use `{{ data.a }}` then it will correctly display `25.2`, however if I run the above code, then the `else` statement is always displayed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: use > and tell what happen

Comment: Same thing happens. I have tried all the operators

Comment: make sure data.a is int type not string

Comment: I just tried adding `int()` around the data before it's added to the database and it didn't work (would it perhaps change to a string when added to the database?)

Comment: must be float, has decimal

Comment: What much be a float? I know `a` is a float, but that shouldn't affect the comparison right?

Comment: What's the point of doing this in template?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do these operations in the template, the simply convert your variables to string and it should work:

```
{% if "29.3" < "29.2" %}
   <p>correct</p>
{% else %}
   <p>incorrect</p>
{% endif %}
```

> incorrect

```
{% if "29.1" < "29.2" %}
   <p>correct</p>
{% else %}
   <p>incorrect</p>
{% endif %}
```

> correct

You can put everything together by using [stringformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat) filter. Goodluck,